# How to exit and remove Pssession without prompt for session number

Tags: powershell

The suggested post does not discuss exiting and removing the pssession.

This code snippet is going to be used as part of a GUI toolbox, so the user will not have access to the PS console. The script performs almost perfect except for exiting and removing the Pssession at the end.

```
$name = "Remote PC Name"
CMD /C SC \\$name Start WinRM
New-PSSession -ComputerName $name
Get-PSSession
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $name
(Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint C).Keyprotector  | Out-GridView
Get-BitLockerVolume
exit-pssession
Get-pssession
Remove-PSSession
CMD /C SC \\$name Stop WinRM
```

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` is meant for interactive purposes. You would need to use `Invoke-Command` in this case

Comment: Use `Invoke-Command` instead of `Enter-`/`Exit-PSSession`

Comment: Because I am trying to retrieve the Bitlocker key I Enter a pssession. without entering a pssession it pulls the key from the local pc it is run from.